# Set Visual Studio to target Windows Phone 7 emulator by default?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7

I installed a new Windows Phone 7 template this week in Visual Studio, and now every time I open a project, VS sets the default debugging environment to target my physical phone instead of the emulator. It's annoying, because 9 times out of 10 I want to debug locally, and I hit F5 only to get the "Zune software is not launched. Retry after making sure that Zune software is launched." error.

Has anyone figured out how to set the default back to the Windows Phone 7 emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default Deployment Target

When you install the January 2011 Update, the default deployment target for Windows Phone Projects in Visual Studio changes to Windows Phone 7 Device. You can change the default target to Windows Phone 7 Emulator by using the following steps:

1. Close all Visual Studio and Windows Phone Emulator instances.
2. Delete the contents of %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Phone Tools\CoreCon.
3. Restart Visual Studio.

[Source](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/6/6D66958D-891B-4C0E-BC32-2DFC41917B11/Release%20Notes%20-%20January%202011%20Update.htm)

Comment: Worked like a charm, Martin. I also installed the January 2011 update this week, but didn't notice the change until after I was playing with the new template. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have same issue with WP8 SDK not showing deployment targets(dont know for what reason) in VS or Blend also resolved with this trick.

Answer (score 1):

I have an easy way. Go to visual studio -> tools -> setting and then select expert setting.

Comment: How does that accomplish what the question was asking?