# VS2010 defaults WP7 apps to "Windows Phone 7 Device" instead of Emulator

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set Visual Studio to target Windows Phone 7 emulator by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127253/set-visual-studio-to-target-windows-phone-7-emulator-by-default)

After installing the latest WP7 dev updates (the one that adds copy/paste-ready) and the emulator updates, my VS defaults all WP7 projects to "Windows Phone 7 **Device**" instead of "Windows Phone 7 **Emulator**".

Prior to this update, it always defaulted to emulator. I can't figure out how to get that back - I've searched everywhere and can't locate any configuration from inside VS. Does anyone know of a way to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Already answered here - [Set Visual Studio to target Windows Phone 7 emulator by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127253/set-visual-studio-to-target-windows-phone-7-emulator-by-default)

Comment: thanks for finding that. i'm moving to close this question.